# alert message on UploadStart - ajaxFileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to check if the user ticked the checkbox BEFORE the file is uploaded to the server, so I created a validation on UploadStart with an alert message. I put the break point at this line and it did go through, but the alert message still didn't show.

(AjaxFileUpload control is not put under any UpdatePanel)

```
 protected void AjaxFileUpload3_UploadStart(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadStartEventArgs e)
 {
     if(CheckBox1.Checked == false)
     {
         System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('Please accept our TnC, bla bla bla');", true);
         return;
     }
 }
```

I don't want to use javascript, am I doing this right? Please advise me.

Comment: show your view/aspx page code

Answer (score 0):

try to have a global boolean variable `bool isCheck = false;`
In the event of the `CheckBox1_Checked(obje...,...)`

or `CheckBox1_Tick` (i dont know the default name.)
add this `isCheck = true`

And in your condition:

```
 protected void AjaxFileUpload3_UploadStart(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadStartEventArgs e)
 {
     if(isCheck == false)
     {
         System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('Please accept our TnC, bla bla bla');", true);
         return;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**i don't want to use javascript** but in your code it shows you using javascript ..

```
 System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('Please accept our TnC, bla bla bla');", true);
```

If you want to put any validation at client side you must have to use javascript otherwise I dont think it possible without using javascript

Here is e.g. how to handle event before upload using javascript in `ajax-uploader` control

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc2" %>
    <script lang="javascript">
        function UploadStart(sender, args) {
            alert("Started");
          // validate ur checkbox is checked or not 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <cc2:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc2:ToolkitScriptManager>

  <cc2:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1"    AllowedFileTypes="pdf"   
   MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" OnClientUploadStart="UploadStart" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

IF you want to cancel current upload

```
 function UploadStart(sender, args) {
                alert("Started");
              // validate ur checkbox is checked or not 

             //cancel current upload
              args.set_cancel(true);
      // try using return false      
      return false;
            }
```

Comment: based on ur code, how to cancel the upload if the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: Asnwer Edited check,,

Comment: i cannot use args.set_cancel(true). ERROR:Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function